# Why does dereferencing an uninitialised pointer not crash here?

Tags: c++, pointers

I try to run this code, it is built with only a warning ('a' maybe uninitialized in this function ....) but during run time my computer crash and only show "Hello world!".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
 int p=20;
 int *a;
 *a=p;
 cout << *a << endl;
 cout << &p << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

However when I omit this part:

```
cout << &p << endl;
```

Again I will have the same warning but the code work properly. Anyone can explain what's going on?

Thank's before.

Comment: `*a=p;` is undefined behavior, since you didn't initialize the pointer with a valid memory address.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined, it does not work properly even though it appears to

Comment: @milleniumbug: OP knows this. OP is asking why it "works properly" when the address of `p` is not taken.

Comment: did you mean to write `a = &p;` ?

Comment: Warnings are not just to fill the build output - you must fix them, always!

Answer (score 7):

As you must have read a billion times by now, undefined behaviour means that anything can happen.

In practice, in this case, if you don't take the address of `p` then the compiler doesn't need to make it an actual "object" and can just resolve everything to do with it at compile-time. So a command to output an indeterminate value is being "baked in" to your program, despite the logical invalid dereference. This is still undefined behaviour but there's no memory access at runtime that'll cause the operating system to make your program crash.

Just initialise your variable, as you are supposed to.

Heed warnings.